# Find div and change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following table, I want to choose an option and toggle the color between them. but can not repeat (only one option should be in green...) I've tried everything... =/

```
$(".roundedOpt").click(function(){ 
    var opt = $(this);
    $(opt).attr("style","background:#4AA14A;");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HVw7E/326/

Comment: less pain if you add and remove classes with javascript that include your css properties :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To toggle one in each list, do

```
$(".roundedOpt").on('click', function () {
    var opts = $(this).closest('td').find('.roundedOpt');

    opts.not(this).css('background', '#337AB7');
    $(this).css('background', '#4AA14A');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe6c1a7m/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable for this, just use this. :) And I just reset all your blue items to blue first, then set the this clicked item to green. I upudated your js fiddle with this:

```js
$(".roundedOpt").click(function()
                        { 
    $(".roundedOpt").removeAttr("style");
    $(this).attr("style","background:#4AA14A;");   
});
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
}
.roundedOpt {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: #337AB7;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
 font-size: 11.5px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.dleft {
 position: absolute;
}

div.dright{
    width:auto;
 padding-left:24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="trDetail1">

 <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
  <span>Options list #1</span>
 </td>
  <td class="text-justify" style="">
   <div style="float:right;padding-left:5px;">
   </div><p>Select an option below:</p>

   <div style="padding-top:5px;">

    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">A</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option A.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">B</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option B.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">C</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option C.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">D</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option D.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">E</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option E.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
    <br/>
    <tr id="trDetail2">

 <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
  <span>Options list #2</span>
 </td>
  <td class="text-justify" style="">
   <div style="float:right;padding-left:5px;">
   </div><p>Select an option below:</p>

   <div style="padding-top:5px;">

    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">A</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option A.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">B</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option B.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">C</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option C.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">D</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option D.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
     <div class="dleft">
         <div class="roundedOpt">E</div>
     </div>
     <div class="dright">Option E.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take off your style on click

```
$(".roundedOpt").click(function(){
    $(".roundedOpt").attr("style","");                    
    var opt = $(this);
    $(opt).attr("style","background:#4AA14A;");         
});
```

[Look at this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m91gpck/)

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but the @adeneo code was needed!
The option list 2, it's independent of the option list 1.